# use of pointer while using strstr function in c programming

Tags: c

I have this following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
char line1[30],line2[30],*chp;
puts("Enter line1:");
gets(line1);
puts("Enter Line2");
gets(line2);
chp=strstr(line1,line2);
if(chp)
printf("%s String is present in Given String",line2);
else
printf("%s String is not present in Given String",line2);
getche();
}
```

I know chp is a pointer in this program , i doubt chp will store one memory location , but how the memory location of string (line2) is stored in chp pointer , please programmers help me to understand this program.

Comment: First, indent your program. Second, don't ever use `gets`, use `fgets`or `gets_s` instead.

Comment: Your question really is: *What is a pointer?* Learn some tutorials on basic C.

Comment: "i doubt chp will store one memory location" - huh? it's a pointer, it will store a memory location... "but how the memory location of string (line2) is stored in chp pointer" - well, you **just** assigned the return value of `strstr()` to it...

Comment: @YuHao: Third, it's `int main(void)`, not `void main()`. Fourth, if you're using a book that tells you to use `void main()`, please tell us which book it is so we can advise people to avoid it; its author doesn't know C very well.

Comment: Actually Keith if you want to get super correct it's `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` whichever you prefer.

Comment: @Ion No, `int main(void)` is also valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what strstr does is if string2 is located somewhere in string1, it returns a pointer in string1 to where the first occurrence of string2 is located.  This pointer is a char pointer.  Meaning it's memory allocation is sizeof(char).

I'm assuming you don't quite understand pointers so i'll give you a quick tutorial.  So what a pointer is, is basically a variable that contains the location in memory of something else.  It essentially points to somewhere else in memory.  This case, you have line1 located somewhere on your computer in memory, say computer address 0-29.  What chp does is just store where in that address range of 0-29 line2 starts.  So if your line1 is "hello there people" and line2 is there.  then chp will be pointing to address 6, which is where "there" starts in line1.  It's only a pointer though, it does not contain the whole memory.  Only line1 contains the whole memory for the string.  Pointers only ever point to a location in memory, and aren't the memory variables themselves.  Does this help?

Comment: yes i understand the pointers , my doubt is i can use strchr instead of strstr if i want to search for a single variable , but for searching a string , the function strstr is used  and the  memory address of the string (i.e., line2) is stored in chp.this only confuses me . even for searching a variable i am using chp=strchr(line1,character) and also for searching a string i am using the single pointer i.e., chp=strstr(line1,line2)

Comment: chp will update every time, it just points to somewhere in memory.  It's like having x = 5; then x = 10; It doesn't hold more than one address

Comment: thanking you programmer :)

Answer (score 1):

The strstr function searches within the string pointed to by s1 for the string pointed to by s2. **It returns a pointer to the first occurrence in s1 of s2.**

Therefore it stores only **one memory location,** the pointer to where the line2 is found in line1, otherwise null..

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that a user runs your program and enters strings like this:

```
 Enter line1:
 StackOverflow
 Enter line2:
 Over
```

gets() will write the string "StackOverflow.com" into the line1 array, and the string "Over" into the line2 array.

Let's imagine (just for the sake of discussion) that the line1 array is located in memory at address 0x1000.  A memory dump (showing each byte's address in memory, followed by the character that is stored there) might look like this:

```
0x1000   S
0x1001   t
0x1002   a
0x1003   c
0x1004   k
0x1005   O
0x1006   v
0x1007   e
0x1008   r
0x1009   f
0x100A   l
0x100B   o
0x100C   w
0x100D   \0  (i.e. the NUL terminator byte that indicates the end of the string)
[and the remaining 16 bytes of the array are undefined garbage, so we'll ignore them]
```

What strstr() is going to do in this case is look for the first instance of the substring "Over" in the above array, and return a pointer to first char of that substring if it finds it.  So in this case, strstr() would return the value 0x1005, since that is the memory location of the "O" character in "Over".

If the first string did not contain the second string, strstr() would return NULL instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char line1[30];
    char line2;                 // here is a char  not char []
    char *chp;
    puts("Enter line1:");
    fgets(line1,30,stdin);      // use fgets
    puts("Enter Line2");
    line2 = fgetc(stdin);
    chp=strchr(line1,line2);
    if(chp)
        printf("%s String is present in Given String",chp);
    else
        printf("%s String is not present in Given String",line2);
    return 0;
}
```